# Weird Zoom Button style in Google Map. Anyone has any ideas?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-maps

I'm using google map JS api on the map. And the this is a wordpress website. I'm adding a google map to the contact page template. But, there are some really weird things. The Zoom In and Zoom Out button style is not + and -. Anyone has any ideas? How can I have the default + - button?
[JS fiddle for the Google Map Codes:](https://jsfiddle.net/kylops/067506vL/)

```js
var map;
 function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   mapTypeControl: false,
   zoom: <?php echo $map_zoom;?>,
   zoomControl: true,
   scrollwheel: false,
   zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.DEFAULT
   },
   panControl: false,
   streetViewControl: false,
   scaleControl: false,
   overviewMapControl: false,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $contact_info['map']['lat'];?>,<?php echo $contact_info['map']['lng'];?>)
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
   mapOptions);

  var infoContent = '<div class="window-content"><h4><?php echo bloginfo('name');?></h4><div class="contact-address" itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><?php if(isset($contact_info['address_1']) ):?><span itemprop="streetAddress"><?php echo $contact_info['address_1'];?><?php if(isset($contact_info['address_2']) ):?>,<br/><?php echo $contact_info['address_2']; ?> <?php endif;?></span><br/><?php endif;?><?php if(isset($contact_info['city']) ):?><span itemprop="addressLocality"><?php echo $contact_info['city'];?></span>&nbsp;<?php endif;?><?php if(isset($contact_info['postcode']) ):?><span itemprop="postalCode"><?php echo $contact_info['postcode'];?></span>&nbsp;<?php endif;?><?php if(isset($contact_info['state']) ):?><span itemprop="addressRegion"><?php echo $contact_info['state'];?></span><?php endif;?><?php if(isset($contact_info['country']) ):?><br/><span itemprop="addressCountry"><?php echo $contact_info['country'];?></span><?php endif;?></div></div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: infoContent
  });

  var icon = {
   path: 'M16.5,51s-16.5-25.119-16.5-34.327c0-9.2082,7.3873-16.673,16.5-16.673,9.113,0,16.5,7.4648,16.5,16.673,0,9.208-16.5,34.327-16.5,34.327zm0-27.462c3.7523,0,6.7941-3.0737,6.7941-6.8654,0-3.7916-3.0418-6.8654-6.7941-6.8654s-6.7941,3.0737-6.7941,6.8654c0,3.7916,3.0418,6.8654,6.7941,6.8654z',
   anchor: new google.maps.Point(16.5, 51),
   fillColor: '<?php echo $map_marker_colour;?>',
   fillOpacity: 0.6,
   strokeWeight: 0,
   scale: 1
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $contact_info['map']['lat'];?>,<?php echo $contact_info['map']['lng'];?>),
   map: map,
   icon: icon,
   title: 'marker'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkPLZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure when you do your own style, do not let any img style overwrite the google map img style.
By default it is `.gm-style img{ max-width: none; }`
If you have to use !important on some img tag,
Then use: `.gm-style img{ max-width: none !important; }` to fix.

Comment: I also suggest to preface whatever styles you are about to override with the classname of the container where your map is, if you're just going to use it once or twice, ex. `.container .my-map {}`